# Configure SSL for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ssl, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a trouble to display the lock next to my website. So I am trying to follow the instruction on this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html) to assign ACM certificate to my Elastic Beanstalk by configuring Elastic Load Balancer. I assigned my SSL certificate id which I have created before and applied to the environment. However, I don't see any thing change after the update. My website doesn't display the lock next to it's name. I checked the AWS Certificate Manager and see that the certificate is in use.

Can anybody tells where should I look to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you force the https for the app? and when you got the SSL for what domain did you got that certificate www or non www?

Comment: I turned listener port to 80 and secure listener port to 443. I used Amazon Certificate Manager to request the certificate and it seems that ACM treats www or non www same way. But to answer your question, no, I didn't get the certificate without www

Comment: What is your domain

Comment: I am not able to tell you that. Sorry about that. Do you have suggestions about this problem?

Comment: So when you type your domain in browser for example domain.com does it redirects to www.domain.com or vice versa?

Comment: I just checked my website and it says the certificate is not valid. [Update] The reason is because host name is mismatch.

Comment: no, it doesn't redirect to www.domain. com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the certificate will be invalid because as per comment you did not get the certificate for non www domain and your naked domain is not redirecting to www.domain.com.

So you have to get a new certificate for both www and non-www domain when you request the certificate there is option check below screenshot. And then you force the https on the application. And your site will serve through SSL certificate.

[image]

Comment: I requested a new certificate with www. But it doesn't fit the problem.

Comment: But if I type http://www.domain.com, then there is a lock next to my domain. Guest I need to redirect my www.domain.com and domain.com to that Url.

Comment: Yes that will work too but better you have that ssl for both domains.

Comment: Thank for your big help. I don't know how to configure ssl for both domains, but I will look it up.